# CSS - Formatting Forms with label tags

Tags: css, forms

I've got a form that I'm trying to layout semantically and format with CSS. As it's produced dynamically (from ASP.NET MVC) some elements may be rendered as text rather than input tags as they may be read-only for that screen. I am trying to add a width to the label tags to neaten up the form and align the values/value boxes, but it seems I can only do this if I float them (is that correct?). That works OK for when I have rendered values after the label tag, but if the value is blank the left float seems to stack against the previous label, even though both are contained within p tags (these should be block level, yes?). What, if anything, am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" /><title>

    Edit

</title>
        <!-- Next Style Section Is Just To Set Up Classes, it will be moved to .CSS file -->
        <style type="text/css">
            div.FieldGroup {background-color: Blue; }
            p.Field { display: block; }
            span.NoteHeader { font-style: italic;}
            label { float: left; width: 150px;} 
        </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">


    <h2>Edit</h2>



    <form action="" method="post">
        <div id="MainSection" class="FieldGroup">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Person Identification</legend>
                <p class="Field">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    Name
                </p>
                <p class="Field">
                    <label for="Colour">ChildStatus:</label>
                    <select id="Colour" name="Colour">
                        <option value="10">Red</option>
                        <option value="20">Yellow</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="30">Orange</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p class="Field">
                    <label for="Age">Age:</label>
                    <input id="Age" name="Age" type="text" value="" />

                </p>
                <p class="Field">
                    <label>Birthplace:</label>
                </p>
                <p class="Field">
                    <label for="Reference">Reference:</label>
                    <input id="Reference" name="Reference" type="text" value="" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Cheers

MH

(P.S. - I can't add in readonly textboxes to contain these blanks as they want plain text if they can't change the value)

Comment: Any reason you are wrapping your label/inputs in paragraph elements?  That may work fine, but semantically shouldn't they be divs?  Maybe it's thinking too much on my part, but one thing I can think of is you're gonna want to explicitly set a lot of boring style values in the p.Field style because browsers all add different things to p tags (margins and padding especially) and rarely is any one browser the same on that.  At least with a div you know most browsers should be treating it as a container only with all style defaults to 0 or blank.

Comment: I've changed that to try it, but it doesn't make any difference to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add clear:both to your p.Field declaration:

```
p.Field { 
   display: block; 
   clear: both; 
}
```

Comment: thanks, someone else on another form suggested clear: left and this seems to suffice.

Comment: I changed the ps to divs, this worked a lot better (the ps were VS's default)

Answer (score 0):

Add a clear:left property to the label's css.

Comment: this doesn't work, it means the following input box moves up to the end of the preceding line

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to float your `label`s in order to set their width, you just need to change their `display` to `block`. If you are floating them though, their containing `p` blocks won't expand to surround them unless given an `overflow` of `hidden` or `auto`. Clearing the `label` can also work to keep them from stacking, but it all depends on the look you want.